# Apply --tls-min-v1.0 on NextJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, tls1.2

On our legacy system, we have a workaround to run the production server with
`node --tls-min-v1.0 server` but I don't see something like that in NextJS.

Also researched about `next.config.js`, if I can find something, but couldn't.

If someone have had this issue and figured out a way to do it please let me know.

> NOTE: Don't want to create a different/custom server for that, and would like
> to use Next server itself

---

Scripts in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to it:

`NODE_OPTIONS='--tls-min-v1.0' yarn dev`

In case if others might have the same issue.

Reference: [**Next CLI**](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli)